# Reducing a matrix of feature vectors to a single, meaningful vector

Tags: machine-learning, pca, feature-selection

I have matrices of feature vectors - 200 features long, in which the feature vectors within a matrix are temporally related, but I wish to reduce each matrix to a single, meaningful vector. I have applied PCA to the matrix in order to reduce its dimensionality to one with high variance, and am considering concatenating its rows together into one feature vector to summarize the data.

Is this a sensible approach, or are there better ways of achieving this?

Comment: Just try to do whatever you want next, if you achieve nice classification accuracy - it was sensible. If not - try another feature extraction/selection technique, or keep more features instead of 1, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an n x 200 feature matrix, where n is your number of samples, and 200 features per sample, and each feature is temporally related to all others? Or you have individual feature matrices, one for each time point, and you want to run PCA on each of these individual feature matrices to find a single eigenvector for that time point, and then concatenate those together?

PCA seems more useful in the second case.

While this is doable, this is maybe not the best way to go about it because you lose temporal sensitivity by collapsing together features from different times. Even if each feature in your final feature matrix represents a different time, most classifiers cannot learn about the fact that feature 2 follows feature 1 etc. So you lose the natural temporal ordering by doing this.

If you care about the the temporal relationship between these features you may want to take a look at recurrent neural networks, which allow you feed information from t-1 into a node, at the same time as feeding in your current t features. So in a sense they learn about the relationship between t-1 and t features which will help you preserve temporal ordering. See this for an explanation: http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/

If you don't care about time and just want to group everything together, then yes PCA will help reduce your feature count. Ultimately it depends what type of information you think is more relevant to your problem.